# Win10 install - stuck after connexion to microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-installation, reinstall

I just resetted my windows install via the option to format in the win10 settings

I go through region and keyboard setup, and then it wanted me to login in my microsoft account. I enter my information, and then a please wait screen, for 2 hours.

Is it supposed to hang at this point or do i have a problem?
[image]

Comment: select offline acount in setup, later after windows is fully installed, go to settings app and convert the account to MicrosoftAccount

Comment: have you tried my workaround?

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so [that you can accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setup hangs while using Microsoft Account, you can select to use offline account

[image]

[image]

Now finish the setup of Windows 10. Now go to the [settings app to convert the local account to a Microsoft Account](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5375-switch-microsoft-account-windows-10-a.html)

[image]